# LLVM Input module is broken

Tags: llvm

I am busy to test a Pascal LLMV compiler:
https://gitlab.com/mseide-msegui/mselang

All went OK, the MSElang compiler produce a Bitcode File (`helloworld.bc`).

But when trying to compile that `bc` file with opt there is that error message
afer +- 900 lines of messages of the opt compiler.

```
/usr/bin/opt: /home/fred/mlctest/hellomlc.bc: error: input module is broken!
```

Where is the problem, do  you have a idea what appends?

Answer (score 0):

Re-hello.

Some more infos...

The .bc (Bit-Code) file produced by MSElang is perfectly recognized by lli (llvm interpreter & dynamic compiler).

See picture:
[bc file interpreted by lli](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JnjdN.png)

But it I try to compile it with llc with this:

```
llc /home/fred/mlctest/hellomlc.bc
```

there is that error message after lot of messages:

```
llc: /home/fred/mlctest/hellomlc.bc: error: input module is broken!
```

What is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The error, whatever it is, is usually easily located by calling [verifyFunction()](http://llvm.org/doxygen/namespacellvm.html#a26389c546573f058ad8ecbdc5c1933cf) and/or [verifyModule()](http://llvm.org/doxygen/namespacellvm.html#af8c14262d42a312c9026452162c9e0a6) before writing the module. Those functions report actionable details.

VerifyModule() calls verifyFunction(), so you don't strictly need verifyFunction(), but you may find convenient to call verifyFunction() as soon as you have generated a function and assert that it returns false. That way you get one or a few helpful messages instead of the flood verifyModule() may give you.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I will use those verify...() methods. The problem came from the debug infos.  Without enabling debug info the compilation is ok.